# Why is my displacement map virtually completely grey?

Tags: texture-baking, displacement

I'm working on a displacement map to display details from a high-poly mesh on a low-poly mesh. However, when I bake my displacement map, it appears almost completely grey.

[image: A screenshot of my blender workspace.]

What's causing this? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to bake a *Displacement Map*, but looking in your file shows you have no displaced mesh. What you want to do is create a *Height Map* from existing geometry.

This is a solution if someone experiences the same problem but has a displaced mesh: Check if you have applied the *Displace Modifier* and set *Level Viewport* to 0 in the *Multires Modifier* before baking the displacement.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had the level viewport set to 0, and baked again. However, I'm encountering the same issue: https://i.imgur.com/UMV6auL.png

Comment: Well, without any more details or the blend file to investigate further it's hard to say where the problem is. In your screenshot there is only a Texture node. Is there actually any displacement applied or is it just geometry?

Comment: [Here's my .blend file!](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HKw5AnasMp_MMWdBwpWwwWeFJqngqr1N/view?usp=sharing)

I'm trying to get blender to bake a displacement map from the DetailedCup object for later use on the Cup object.

I only had an image texture node to select when baking so that blender knows what to bake to.

Comment: But the DetailedCup object is not generated through displacement, it's a different geometry. That's not how baking displacement maps (from a displaced mesh) works. What you want to do is create a height map of existing geometry to use it as a displacement map. Here's a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=arvhK4tvYuY&feature=emb_logo) about it, for example. But to do that, the height is measured by distance to camera so to project it onto your UV map you would have to place the object's geometry flat on the ground in the shape of the UV map.

Comment: @MEATTAIL Edited the answer so it fits your problem but also helps people who have this problem with a displaced mesh.

Comment: Thank you! I have some additional questions:

"Here's a video tutorial about it, for example." - I've seen this video before, but it only seems to work on a single plane.

"to project it onto your UV map you would have to place the object's geometry flat on the ground in the shape of the UV map" - How would I do so? Again, thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, it works on a single plane because the height is determined by the distance to the camera - this way it cannot work (correctly) on other meshes. To flatten the mesh to the UV there are some results on Google, leading to scripts that might work more or less. Then the next problem would be, that these scripts make the meshes flat as supposed - but that means there's no height for a height map anymore. The last bigger problem is, while your simple cup has clean UVs, the detailed is a mess. This will never work with overlapping UV faces, because they would share the same height information.

Comment: Not enough characters so I had to split my answer. Back to overlapping faces, for example the edges of the top rim are stretched diagonal across the UV map. The "knobs" are huge and placed across all other UVs. This is not a proper UV layout to work with so that's another main reason why it won't work the way you want it. Don't get me wrong, no offense intended: have you worked much with UVs before? Watched tutorials on UV unwrapping and how to use UVs?